# Subscriber callback not being called in C++

Tags: ros, c++, ros-groovy, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to subscribe to a topic and trigger a callback function. Following the wikipage on subscribers, I wrote the following lines (since I am dealing with C++ namespaces):

```
ros::Subscriber ekf_sub = nh_.subscribe("/ardrone/predictedPose", queue_size_, &VisualOdometry::ekf_callback, this);

void VisualOdometry::ekf_callback(const tum_ardrone::filter_state::ConstPtr& ekf_msg){
std::cout<<"EKF callback function reached "<<std::endl;}
```

I have used "rostopic list" and rqt to verify the topic "/ardrone/predictedPose" is being published while my program is running. I have used "rostopic info" to verify that the topic is of type "tum_ardrone/filter_state".

In my subscriber constructor, "nh_" is a public nodehandle that is successfully used in the class ("VisualOdometry") for other subscribers. "queue_size_" is simply an int set to 5, and "this" is the pointer to the instance of the class "VisualOdometry" (since that's where the code is located).

I have further verified that the subscriber constructor line is executed, but my callback function is never called. Any help or tips on how to debug is much appreciated since I'm unsure of what to do. I am using ROS Groovy.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67351/subscriber-callback-not-being-called-in-c++/) by [bja](https://answers.ros.org/users/4882/bja/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2013-07-15

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2013-07-15**:
Under what context are you running this? Is this a thread?

**Comment by [bja](https://answers.ros.org/users/4882/bja/) on 2013-07-15**:
The class "VisualOdometry" is being run as a node, and is currently subscribing to rgb and depth images from a Kinect. I'm trying to make it also subscribe to the above topic.

**Comment by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on 2013-07-15**:
Everything looks right, assuming it's a typo that the topic is of type "tum_ardrone/filter/state" and is actually of type "tum_ardrone/filter_state."  Are you [spinning](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning)?

**Comment by [bja](https://answers.ros.org/users/4882/bja/) on 2013-07-15**:
Yes that was a typo, I changed it in my description, thanks. And yes within the node code, after the "VisualOdometry" object is created, "ros::spin()" is executed.

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2013-07-15**:
Everything seems legit. Just check once that you are  continuously polling for message by using spinning appropriately.

**Comment by [thebyohazard](https://answers.ros.org/users/1483/thebyohazard/) on 2013-07-15**:
Is this node run by a launch file or a rosrun command? Because with roslaunch the default isn't for output to show on the screen. You have to change output="screen" in the node tag. [link](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roslaunch/XML/node)

**Comment by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) on 2013-07-15**:
Are messages being published on the topic?  You can check with `rostopic echo`.

**Comment by [bja](https://answers.ros.org/users/4882/bja/) on 2013-07-15**:
I am using a launch file and output is already set to "screen". I verified again that by doing "rostopic echo /ardrone/predictedPose" the topic is publishing messages (I also observe this in rqt, that rostopic is subscribed to the topic).

**Comment by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) on 2013-07-15**:
Are you using a bag file to publish this data??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What scope is the variable `ekf_sub` at?  If it's automatic, and goes away at the end of the function it's in, then the subscriber will be shut down when it goes out of scope.  To make it persistent, it should be a member variable of your class.

---

Originally posted by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) with karma: 1263 on 2013-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 12

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bja](https://answers.ros.org/users/4882/bja/) on 2013-07-15**:
That was exactly my problem, I wasn't declaring "ekf_sub" in my header file and it was thus going out of scope. My callback function is now reached; thank you very much!

**Comment by [GPrathap](https://answers.ros.org/users/31593/gprathap/) on 2018-10-17**:
You save my dayyyy!!!, thank youu